# Campagnolo Large Flange Pista (track) hubs

Tags: hub, campagnolo, track-racing

I haven't any direct experience with vintage Campagnolo large flange pista/track hubs.

Can anyone tell me if there are issues with mounting a 70-80s era 5-6 speed road freewheel and using them just like any other road/race hubs?  (a freewheel with matching Italian threading, of course)

Comment: I don't have any experience with these either, but you wouldn't expect a track hub to run a multispeed freewheel.

Comment: On a fixie, yes. Wouldn't work with a freewheel of more than 3 cogs.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a fixed cog or a single-cog BMX-style freewheel easily on a track (pista) hub, but the wheel dish is way too far out on the drive side to fit a 5 or greater freewheel cassette.

In other words there is simply just not enough room between the hub flange and the frame to support a wider cassette. Modern multi-speed hubs have the spoke flange set in further towards the center on the drive side. Track hubs do not.